# Python "String index out of range" when trying to read string data from an external file

Tags: python, indexing, traceback

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "script.py", line 16, in <module>
        if char[x] == " ":
IndexError: string index out of range
```

for these lines of code

```
for file in files:
    f = open(file, "r")
    file_num += 1
    for line in file:
       for char in line:
           if char[x] == " ":
              break
           else:
              x += 1
```

I'm trying to get it to read a file line by line and pick out the region between spaces to store as string variables elsewhere in the script. I'm pretty much a total noob so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @free_mind It wouldn't do anything. If `line` isn't iterable, then the loop won't be entered. The issue is `char[x]` which doesn't make sense since 1) `x` isn't defined 2) `x` is never reset between loops 3)`char` is supposed to be a string of length 1

Comment: char is already a character, not a string so you should do `if char == " ":`

Answer (score 2):

`char` will always be a string of length 1.
After some `char`s are not `' '`, `x` will be some value which is greater than `0` (which I assume this is what `x` is initialized to). Then you are getting the `IndexError`.

Your code can be greatly simplified to:

```
for file in files:
    f = open(file, "r")
    file_num += 1
    for line in file:
       for char in line:
           if char == ' ':
              break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_num = len(files)
for file in files:
  with open(file, 'r') as f: # with closes the file for you
    words = line.split() # split the line by white space into a list
```